# Fill NA values by a two levels indexed Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns (`A`, `B` and `value`) where there are missing values in the `value` column. And there is a Series indexed by two columns (`A` and `B`) from the dataframe. How can I fill the missing values in the dataframe with corresponding values in the series?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data and your desired output?

Comment: Basically, @jezrael has just got me right there I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,3],
                   'B': [2,3,4],
                   'value':[2,np.nan,np.nan] })

print (df)
   A  B  value
0  1  2    2.0
1  1  3    NaN
2  3  4    NaN

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,3],[2,3,4]])
s = pd.Series([5,6,0,8,9,7], index=idx)
print (s)
1  2    5
   3    6
   4    0
3  2    8
   3    9
   4    7
dtype: int64

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])['value'].fillna(s).reset_index()
print (df)
   A  B  value
0  1  2    2.0
1  1  3    6.0
2  3  4    7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe and series `df` and `s`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('aaabbbccc'),
        B=list('xyzxyzxyz'),
        value=[1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, 9]
    ))

s = pd.Series(range(1, 10)[::-1])
s.index = [df.A, df.B]
```

We can `fillna` with a clever `join`

```
df.fillna(df.join(s.rename('value'), on=['A', 'B'], lsuffix='_'))
#                   \_____________/                 \_________/ 
#                   make series same                  get old
#                    name as column                  column out
#                    we are filling                  of the way

   A  B  value
0  a  x    1.0
1  a  y    2.0
2  a  z    7.0
3  b  x    4.0
4  b  y    5.0
5  b  z    4.0
6  c  x    7.0
7  c  y    8.0
8  c  z    9.0
```

---

***Timing***
*`join` is cute, but @jezrael's `set_index` is quicker*

```
%timeit df.fillna(df.join(s.rename('value'), on=['A', 'B'], lsuffix='_'))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.56 ms per loop

%timeit df.set_index(['A','B'])['value'].fillna(s).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.06 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hmmm, you can reuse my sample ;)

Comment: @jezrael That's true, I could've... I wasn't thinking at the time or I would have :-)

Comment: I think in future no problem.